# update_post_meta not working in save_post

Tags: save-post, post-meta

I'm having an issue with a function i'm trying to create. It should be simple. When someone saves a post, grab the city/address/province and convert it to long/lat then save that to the database. The problem is, I ca not get "update_post_meta" to work, and I don't understand why.

The code is below, it's simple enough.

```
add_action( 'save_post_dealer', 'save_dealer_long_lat');
function save_dealer_long_lat($post_id) {
    $city = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-dealer-city', true );
    $address = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-dealer-address', true );
    $province = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-dealer-province', true );
    $coords = get_coordinates($city, $address, $province);

    $lat = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-latitude', true );
    $long = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-longitude', true );

    if(empty($lat)) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-latitude', $coords['lat'], $lat);
    }
    if(empty($long)) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-longitude', $coords['long'], $long);
    }
}
```

a few things to eliminate the obvious mistakes.

- yes, the post type is 'dealer' - this function is being run correctly.
- Each of the variables is set properly, I confirmed with a var_dump that they were all set and giving the correct details.
- the get_coordinates function is also working correctly and is giving the proper return.
- the update_post_meta is being reached - the lat/long are empty (no entry for it even exists in the DB)

I don't understand whats going on, everything I see seems to suggest this should be working.

Comment: The 4th argument is `$prev_value`. If $lat is empty, then my guess is that there is no previous value. What if you just try `update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-latitude', $coords['lat'])` and `update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-longitude', $coords['long']);`

Comment: I just tried with a removed $lat and $long from the update_post_meta - there is no change in behaviour.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($lat)` and `var_dump($long)`

Comment: $lat and $long return: string(0) ""

Comment: And what does `var_dump($coords)` look like?

Comment: array(2) { ["lat"]=> float(44.9001922) ["long"]=> float(-76.0219471) }

Comment: Is the `$post_id` the same as the post ID of the post? (Make sure you're not saving the post meta to a revision.) Make sure that WordPress isn't doing an autosave.

Comment: Correct, the $post_id does match the actual posts ID. There are currently 0 entries in the database for wpcf-longitude or wpcf-latitude

Comment: Do have you wp_debug enabled? Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Can you try `$lat_id = update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpcf-latitude', $coords['lat']);` and then `var_dump($lat_id)` and let us know what $lat_id shows

Comment: Huh. It dumps out `bool(false)` . I have WP_debug enabled, nothing occurs. Seems to be no errors.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but I just had this issue where adding a taxonomy term was working, but adding post meta wasn't. The solution was to set a higher priority. The default priority is 10, so try for instance priority of 100:

```
add_action( 'save_post_dealer', 'save_dealer_long_lat', 100, 1);
```